# Controlling windows using keyboard OR another option for WM

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, lubuntu, shortcut-keys, window

I have Ubuntu Minimal installation with Lubuntu Desktop Environment. I want to resize windows using keyboard. Like when you press `Super + Left`, the currently selected window should resize and fill `left half of the screen`. Similar for right. I don`t know whether the lib file required to do such task is pre-installed with minimal version or not.
If it does not come with the required file, please specify the lib file and the command too (command which I need to put in the image below).
If it comes with the required file, what should be the command?
[image]

**Edit**:- Another question is that I cannot directly switch to desktop. Using Alt + Tab, I can only switch between windows and not to the desktop.

**Edit 2**:- (Sorry, I always forget to mention the important stuff.)
I run Lubuntu LXQt version 0.14.1.
Qt version 5.12.8
Build Type - Release
WM - Openbox.
Installed Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)
Is Openbox going to make an update for using those commands? Or is there any other WM which I can use which is better than openbox but has similar resource usage?

Comment: What release?  What do you mean by Lubuntu minimal install?  (it's not implemented yet - https://phab.lubuntu.me/T58) Keyboard shortcuts can be read in the manual (https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/F/keyboard_shortcuts.html which is for the latest *stable* release, as I don't know your release adjust URL to match if needed)

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say I have minimal Ubuntu Installation with Lubuntu DE. I followed [this](https://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/ubuntu-minimal-install) site for installation. And the manual provided above does not have the shortcut which I need for resizing windows.

Comment: It may help in future if you're specific, your screen is missing some shortcuts for Lubuntu so I'm unsure if you're using a LXQt session or Lubuntu session (they are different, esp. regards shortcuts). Meta-D will switch you to to the `pcmanfm-qt` or desktop, and can be used to return you back to where you were (*focal* or 20.04; you haven't mentioned release).  LXQt has no resize, no maximize/minimize functions etc as those are performed by the WM which is `openbox` for Lubuntu (LXQt is WM agnostic) but given I don't know what session, or how you installed your system (not even release)....